# Conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Point" requested

Tags: c++

I have to create a program where a chutist jumps from a plane. The user inputs the altitude and the time when the chutist will open its parachute. I haven't finished all my code, just wanted to know if it can run before I go any further but I always get this error (Conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Point" requested). We are also using the Hortsmann libraries which I am very new to. Anyone knows what this error means and what can I do to fix any error of this kind? If you don't understand my question, please tell me.
    Here is the code:
    #include "ccc_win.h"
    #include

```
using namespace std; 

class Chutist{
public:
 Chutist(); 
 Chutist(Point loc); //constructor where chutist always points up
 void display (int i, int s) const; //accessor function, displays chutist
 void move (int dx, int dy); // mutator function, moves chutist
private:
 Point jumpman;
 Point location; // location of chutist
};

//default

Chutist::Chutist(){
   location = Point (0, 0);
}

//construction of Chutist object at Point loc;

Chutist::Chutist(Point loc){
    jumpman = loc;
}

void Chutist::display(int i, int s) const{
  if (s < i){
     Point top = (jumpman.get_x(), jumpman.get_y());
     Circle c = (top, 10);
     cwin << c;
 }
}

void Chutist::move(int x, int dy){
}



int ccc_win_main(){
   cwin.coord(0, 2000, 2000, 0);
   int loc;
   int altitude = 0;
   int secondstoopen = 0;
   int velocity = 0;
   cout << "Please enter the altitude to jump at." << endl;
   cin  >> altitude;
   cout << "Please enter the time to open the parachute." << endl;
   cin  >> secondstoopen;
   Chutist jumper = Chutist(Point(0, altitude));
   jumper.display(secondstoopen);
}
```

Comment: Which line generates that error?

Comment: Sorry, it;s Point top = (jumpman.get_x(), jumpman.get_y());
     Circle c = (top, 10);

Comment: minimum code to reproduce: `struct Point { Point(int, int){} };` and `Point p = (1, 2);`  Please try to reduce your questions to only leave what is necessary to demonstrate the problem.  Leaving in all of the functions like `display` and `move` are unnecessary. Really you could take out the entire `Chutist` class because it's unrelated to your actual problem.

Comment: Ryan, I think this is the first time OP faces such an error, and most probably has little understanding of its origin. Thus, it'd be strange to expect them to isolate the error like this. They simply seem to stuck at the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in the lines

```
 Point top = (jumpman.get_x(), jumpman.get_y());
 Circle c = (top, 10);
```

where you intend to create instances of `Point` and `Circle`. Which we don't have the corresponding headers, by common sense it's safe to assume that those classes have ctor's that take obvious parameters `(int, int)` and `(Point, int)`. So, the correct way to create an object of a class is either this

```
Point top(jumpman.get_x(), jumpman.get_y());
Circle c(top, 10);
```

or

```
Point top = Point(jumpman.get_x(), jumpman.get_y());
Circle c = Circle(top, 10);
```

which would results in calls to the appropriate constructors.

Your code results in the following. The  expression `(jumpman.get_x(), jumpman.get_y())` evaluates to the rightmost `jumpman.get_t_y()`, that's how the comma operator works. Thus, the compiler concludes that you want to construct a `Point` from a single `int`, which is impossible, since there (obviously) is no such constructor or conversion operator. Same for the second line, with different constructor parameters.

Comment: the reason OP gets the error is that `(x, y)` without anything out in front is just two expressions separated by the comma operator. This is equivalent to `y` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I wasn't sure how the expression with round braces is evaluated. Still, that leads to assignment `Point = int`, which fails. I think this corresponds with my answer?

Comment: It's not assignment because it's at point of creation, so it's trying to call `Point(int)` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Dang. Looks like I should delete the answer now? Thank you for the explanation though, now I'm going to remember how those ctor's work.

Comment: The comma operator will evaluate all the expressions left to right, and the entire expression will evaluate to whatever the rightmost expression is.  Note that this is different than the comma as part of the syntax in something like a function call.

Comment: The answer isn't wrong I just wanted to add *why* that *specific* error shows up.

Comment: Oh alright. I'm a bit nervous trying to help out while still forging my own knowledge. Adding that bit of explanation. (Was in my head when writing the answer, but I couldn't recall how comma funcitons.)

Answer (score 0):

For future references, it was because of the equal sign on the following code:

```
[Point top = (jumpman.get_x(), jumpman.get_y());
 Circle c = (top, 10);]
```

I guess since we are creating the point and the circle we aren't supposed to use an equal sign.

Comment: See the answer above. There can be no "guessing" with programming, it is a precise science. The error is indeed on this line and related to the "equal sign", but the reason is slightly different.